# Jenkins ssh-steps-plugin Auth fail

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to use the **ssh-steps-plugin** to build a pipeline that write files on remote machine using SSH.
I generated a SSH key with **PEM** and copied the public one on remote server (with ssh-copy-id), **so i can connect successfully to the server** with:

```
ssh -i private-keys debian@192.168.0.59
```

Now, i wrote this simple pipeline (is the same found on the github repo of the plugin):

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = "debian"
remote.host = "192.168.0.59"
remote.allowAnyHosts = true

node {
    withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'debian-id', keyFileVariable: 'identity', passphraseVariable: '', usernameVariable: 'debian')]) {
        remote.user = debian
        remote.identityFile = identity
        stage("SSH Steps Rocks!") {
            writeFile file: 'abc.sh', text: 'ls'
            sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done'
            sshPut remote: remote, from: 'abc.sh', into: '.'
            sshGet remote: remote, from: 'abc.sh', into: 'bac.sh', override: true
            sshScript remote: remote, script: 'abc.sh'
            sshRemove remote: remote, path: 'abc.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

I added the credential `debian-id` to globals credential, and the username of my remote machine is **debian**

When i try to execute the pipeline i get this error.

I tried many times to change a little bit the script, but always the same error. I tried to change the **usernameVariable** from **userName** (as shown in the example) to **debian** but didnt works anyway.

What i'm doing wrong ?

**MY SOLUTION**

It seems this error is related to a ssh key with a password. Generating a new key without password i can connect successfully

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:119)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:470)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session$connect$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy:85)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility.retry(Utility.groovy:52)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility$retry.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:83)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connect(ConnectionManager.groovy:59)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$connect.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.wetRun(SessionTask.groovy:61)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.call(SessionTask.groovy:48)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service.run(Service.groovy:81)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.SSHService.executeCommand(SSHService.groovy:177)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution$CommandCallable.execute(CommandStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.call(SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.java:32)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:46)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution.run(CommandStep.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SSHStepExecution.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I am facing same issue, i tried your solution which is generated new key without passowrd, but still getting same error. anything else needs to be done?

Comment: I also encounter this issue, in my case the key already has no password, so I guess there is still something else causing the error

Comment: any updates guys? i also encountered the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to change the (1) passphrase and (2) convert the key to Old Openssh run (on the directory where your key is located):

```
ssh-keygen -p -f id_rsa -m pem
```

--> enter old passphrase (enter)
--> leave empty to remove passphrase (enter)